# Template to check if vector and map contains value

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in `c++` i was searching for templates that could check if a `vector` / `map` independent of their data type, contains a given value, I have found these:

```cpp
template <typename Container, typename Value>
bool vector_contains(const Container& c, const Value& v)
{
    return std::find(std::begin(c), std::end(c), v) != std::begin(c);
}

template< typename container, typename key >
auto map_contains(container const& c, key const& k)
-> decltype(c.find(k) != c.end())
{
    return c.find(k) != c.end();
}
```

My doubt is, does using templates to do this kind of verification impact performance somehow?

Comment: I think the (possibly) SFINAE on `map_contains` is pretty pointless here.

Comment: templates can increase the time it takes to compile, but they don't affect run time speed as the compiler stamps out the template into concrete functions just like you would do if you didn't use a template.

Comment: The templates are gone after compilation. Also, see [`std::map::contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains).

Comment: A C++ programmer knows exactly what `map.find()` and `std::find` does as-is.  If all those templates do is search a vector and a map, what's the reason to create another layer of indirection with your `vector_contains` and `map_contains` classes?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie encapsulation?  I do the same thing when I don't want to have to always be calling `begin` and `end` myself and comparing to `end`.

Comment: "somehow" - sure. Do you want to know whether in positive or negative way? Negative. Which performance? Compile time performance.

Comment: The general issue with these templates is that they return a `bool`.  OK, so in the calling code, if it detects that the item exists, what if now the client wants an iterator to the existing item.  They have to call `find` again.

Comment: @TedLyngmo there's something similar to vectors?

Comment: @Natalia I added some info to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I have found these

Ok, but do analyze them. They are sub optimal and/or plain wrong.

```
template <typename Container, typename Value>
bool vector_contains(const Container& c, const Value& v)
{
    return std::find(std::begin(c), std::end(c), v) != std::begin(c);
}
```

This will return `true` as long as `v` is not the first value found. It'll also return `true` if `v` is not found at all.

A `vector`, without any other information, is unsorted, which means that `contains` will have to search from the first element to the last if the value is not found. Such searches are considered *expensive*.

If you on the other hand [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the `vector` and use the same *Comparator* when using [`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search), it'll have a quicker lookup. Sorting takes time too, though.

---

```
template< typename container, typename key >
auto map_contains(container const& c, key const& k) -> decltype(c.find(k) != c.end())
{
    return c.find(k) != c.end();
}
```

This looks like it may work for types matching the function template. It *should* use `map::contains` instead - if it's meant to be used with `map`s.

Comment: does `ranges::contains` optimize for ordered container? it seems like it simply expect input iterator.

Comment: btw, as pre the link `std::ranges::contains` is `c++23`.

Comment: @appleapple C++23 .... thanks... :-) my eyes... No, I can't see `ranges::contains` changing the fact that a `vector` is unsorted by nature.

Comment: For maps, I'm going to use `.contains()` as you suggested, but for the vector, i didn't understand what you meant

Comment: @Natalia If you want to do a quick `contains` on a `vector`, you¨ll have to sort the `vector`  first. That takes time - but it's worth it if you only sort once and then `std::binary_search` the `vector` many times. If you don't sort the `vector` and search for something found at the near end - it'll have to search though near all the elements.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I originally think you mean it'd automatically dispatch to `map::contains` when it see fit.

Comment: @appleapple `std::ranges` provides some container specific frontends of that sort  (`std::erase_if(std::vector)` and `std::erase_if(std::basic_string)` etc)- but ... nope, not in this case afaik.

Comment: @TedLyngmo why not provide the vector template with `std::binary_search` in your answer instead of just a copy of her templates? I think would be easier to understand your meaning.

Comment: @Nikolas I thought that the `std::binary_search` link would provide the information needed to tie it together. If you find that there's some "glue" missing, please tell me what it is and I'll see if I can improve the answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo just that read this answer make me think `range::contains` would apply to both case (as it comes after the map example).

Comment: @appleapple I get that it could be seen that way. I've removed that part.